# Photoshop: Batch auto-create 100s of shapes changing color from a TXT list

Tags: variables, action, batch-processing, photoshop, batch-rename

I was scratching my head on how to automate and batch process the next.

I want to auto-create many png files, fill the color of the shape and name it from a list.

I made my psd template (rectangle shape),
and have the following txt list (tab separated) +300 items,
containing the color hex value to be filled in, and the name of the image to be created.

```
+--------+-----------+
| HEX    | name      |
+--------+-----------+
| 003366 | A1_003366 |
+--------+-----------+
| 9AB0C7 | B1_9AB0C7 |
+--------+-----------+
| FFFFE5 | A2_FFFFE5 |
+--------+-----------+
| F9F9F3 | B2_F9F9F3 |
+--------+-----------+
| DC143C | A3_DC143C |
+--------+-----------+
| 006866 | B3_006866 |
+--------+-----------+
```

I want my png files named and with their corresponding color. Something like:

```
A1_003366.png
B1_9AB0C7.png
A2_FFFFE5.png
and so on
```

I tried to use variables but cannot see how to change the color and the name of each image to be created.
Is this possible with Photoshop?

Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Where are the shapes you mention defined? Are they triangle, squares or circles? Where did the A1 prefix and B3 prefix come from? What is this list supposed to produce? What OS are you using?

Answer (score 1):

I *think* you're after a way of changing the colour of a live shape, in which case you  can use this scriptlistener code:

```
var myHex = "003366";

//alert(hex_to_dec(myHex));
fill_rectangle(hex_to_dec(myHex));

function hex_to_dec(hexstring)
{
   var hex = hexstring.match(/.{1,2}/g);
   return [
       parseInt(hex[0], 16),
       parseInt(hex[1], 16),
       parseInt(hex[2], 16)
   ]
}

function fill_rectangle(rgb)
{
   var red   = rgb[0];
   var green = rgb[1];
   var blue  = rgb[2];
   // =======================================================
   var idsetd = charIDToTypeID( "setd" );
   var desc23 = new ActionDescriptor();
   var idnull = charIDToTypeID( "null" );
   var ref3 = new ActionReference();
   var idcontentLayer = stringIDToTypeID( "contentLayer" );
   var idOrdn = charIDToTypeID( "Ordn" );
   var idTrgt = charIDToTypeID( "Trgt" );
   ref3.putEnumerated( idcontentLayer, idOrdn, idTrgt );
   desc23.putReference( idnull, ref3 );
   var idT = charIDToTypeID( "T   " );
   var desc24 = new ActionDescriptor();
   var idFlCn = charIDToTypeID( "FlCn" );
   var desc25 = new ActionDescriptor();
   var idClr = charIDToTypeID( "Clr " );
    var desc26 = new ActionDescriptor();
    var idRd = charIDToTypeID( "Rd  " );
    desc26.putDouble( idRd, red ); //red
    var idGrn = charIDToTypeID( "Grn " );
    desc26.putDouble( idGrn, green ); //green
    var idBl = charIDToTypeID( "Bl  " );
    desc26.putDouble( idBl, blue ); //blue
   var idRGBC = charIDToTypeID( "RGBC" );
   desc25.putObject( idClr, idRGBC, desc26 );
   var idsolidColorLayer = stringIDToTypeID( "solidColorLayer" );
   desc24.putObject( idFlCn, idsolidColorLayer, desc25 );
   var idstrokeStyle = stringIDToTypeID( "strokeStyle" );
   var desc27 = new ActionDescriptor();
   var idstrokeStyleVersion = stringIDToTypeID( "strokeStyleVersion" );
   desc27.putInteger( idstrokeStyleVersion, 2 );
   var idfillEnabled = stringIDToTypeID( "fillEnabled" );
   desc27.putBoolean( idfillEnabled, true );
   var idstrokeStyle = stringIDToTypeID( "strokeStyle" );
   desc24.putObject( idstrokeStyle, idstrokeStyle, desc27 );
   var idshapeStyle = stringIDToTypeID( "shapeStyle" );
   desc23.putObject( idT, idshapeStyle, desc24 );
   executeAction( idsetd, desc23, DialogModes.NO );
}
```

Comment: Your code certainly does what I am looking for. How  make the script load the txt file and generate the required +300 png files?
"C:\Desktop\colors\list.txt"
Looks like a bit complicated what I am after. Anyhow, I thank you for your kind help.

Comment: StackOverflow isn't a script writing service. The answer to your question can be found in parts over the internet. Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31074289/is-there-a-script-that-can-transfer-text-from-an-excel-file-into-an-adobe-design) Ignore the excel and card part. Look at the read (readIt) function to get Photoshop to read in a text file